# MPI_Gather MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi

I have implemented the parallel running capability in my simulation code by using MPI_Gather and MPI_Bcast. My MPI knowledge is very limited, however, I have been successful in running my code so far. Recently, I started implementing a new feature. First, I implemented and tested this feature in serial, and it works. Then to implement the parallel capability, I used MPI_Gather, as I have done in the past. This is not working and led to this question.

Let me explain how I use MPI. My simulator is made up of two simulators (simulation of two coupled processes): a master simulator that manages a child simulator and the two exchange information. The master is responsible for creating and managing MPI processes. The root process is responsible for the child simulation. I use Open MPI for the master and OpenMP (the root process spawns multiple threads) for the child. The root process that runs the child simulation needs information from the MPI subprocesses of the master simulator. I use MPI_Gather to transfer this information from all subprocesses to the root, for any given array. As I said, I have used this successfully for three arrays.

When I tried the same thing with the fourth array, I saw that MPI_Gather works as expected for a couple of time steps, and then I get garbage values in the receive buffer in positions corresponding to subprocesses other than root. Since the arrays contain values as a result of solving linear systems in other parts of the code, I tried to simplify the problem with a very simple array that is created just before calling MPI_Gather. I am able to reproduce the same error with the following code in my simulator:

```
MPI_Comm comm;
comm = PETSC_COMM_WORLD;
int nTotProcs;
MPI_Comm_size(comm, &nTotProcs);
int rank=0; MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

// Task: Create an array for each subproc, gather this array in the root
int len=10; double * rbuf;
double a1[len];

// populate the array
for(int i=0; i<len; i++) { 
  a1[i]=rank+i+rank*0.1; 
  std::cout<<"P"<<rank<<" "<<a1[i]<<"\n"; 
}

if(rank==0) rbuf = new double[nTotProcs*len];

int error_code=MPI_Gather(a1,len,MPI_DOUBLE,rbuf,len,MPI_DOUBLE,0,comm);
std::cout<<"errorcode "<<error_code<<"\n";

// MPI error handling
MPI_Errhandler_set(comm, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
if (error_code != MPI_SUCCESS) {
 char error_string[500];
 int length_of_error_string;
 MPI_Error_string(error_code, error_string, &length_of_error_string);
 std::cout<<rank<<": "<<error_string<<"\n";
}

if(rank==0) {
  for(int i=0;i<nTotProcs*len;i++) 
    std::cout<<"rbuf "<<rbuf[i]<<"\n";
  delete[] rbuf;
}
```

The output with two MPI processes (with root spawning 24 threads for the child simulation) is:

```
P0 0
P0 1
P0 2
P0 3
P0 4
P0 5
P0 6
P0 7
P0 8
P0 9
errorcode 0
rbuf 0
rbuf 1
rbuf 2
rbuf 3
rbuf 4
rbuf 5
rbuf 6
rbuf 7
rbuf 8
rbuf 9
rbuf 1.1
rbuf 2.1
rbuf 3.1
rbuf 4.1
rbuf 5.1
rbuf 6.1
rbuf 7.1
rbuf 8.1
rbuf 9.1
rbuf 10.1
P1 1.1
P1 2.1
P1 3.1
P1 4.1
P1 5.1
P1 6.1
P1 7.1
P1 8.1
P1 9.1
P1 10.1
errorcode 0
P0 0
P0 1
P0 2
P0 3
P0 4
P0 5
P0 6
P0 7
P0 8
P0 9
errorcode 1
0: MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer
rbuf 0
rbuf 1
rbuf 2
rbuf 3
rbuf 4
rbuf 5
rbuf 6
rbuf 7
rbuf 8
rbuf 9
rbuf 0.0383135
rbuf 0.0370555
rbuf 0.0375653
rbuf 0.0378906
rbuf 0.0380734
rbuf 0.0381425
rbuf 0.0380751
rbuf 0.0378907
rbuf 0.0375654
rbuf 0.0370555
P1 1.1
P1 2.1
P1 3.1
P1 4.1
P1 5.1
P1 6.1
P1 7.1
P1 8.1
P1 9.1
P1 10.1
errorcode 0
P0 0
P0 1
P0 2
P0 3
P0 4
P0 5
P0 6
P0 7
P0 8
P0 9
errorcode 1
0: MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer
rbuf 0
rbuf 1
rbuf 2
rbuf 3
rbuf 4
rbuf 5
rbuf 6
rbuf 7
rbuf 8
rbuf 9
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
rbuf 0.01
```

The problem is evident in the second and third round of the rbuf output. Instead of being 1.1, 2.1, it is some random values. Actually, I am pretty sure these random values are from another arrays in my code because there are arrays in the code with these values. Before the code crashes, these random values keep changing and taking values from different arrays. The first 10 values that correspond to the root is always correct, 0 to 9.

I have spent 4-5 days trying to debug this issue. There are other MPI_Gather commnds in the code that work fine. I don't understand why this is not working. Which buffer pointer is invalid? I debugged using gdb and I see that rbuf and a1 are valid pointers in root P0 and a1 is valid in subproc P1.

Above code is not a MWE because the entire simulator has other pieces, for example, a piece that assembles the linear system Ax=b and solves it using Newton’s scheme. The computational domain is divided among processes and each subproc is responsible for its set of grid elements in the domain. So I presume each subproc takes different amount of time to reach a certain line of code. Is it mandatory to call MPI_Barrier (or some similar arrangement) before calling MPI_Gather? In the past, I didn’t have to do that. Even after putting barrier before and after gather in the above code, I get the same error.

Comment: Expect the `PETSC_COMM_WORLD`,  `std:cout`  and `“`, this code seems to work fine. I was unable to find any mistake, it compiled well and it worked correctly, giving the expected output. Even inside a loop and with 8 processes...The error might be somewhere else...

Comment: @francis I changed std:cout to std::cout and fixed the quote error due to copy paste on Mac. PETSC_COMM_WORLD can be replaced with MPI_COMM_WORLD, as you probably did. Anyway, I still get the error. I am trying to create a MWE that one can run to reproduce the error, without having the run the full simulator code, but I don't know how. I still think there is some clue in the above code about this error that I am not able to see.